# Node.JS ping server with IP and Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have been struggling to find a way to use node.js to check the response of a server ip that has directory's after it. I can ping a server just with a port but thats not what is required.

**The URL**

> 127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis

**My code so far**

```
var net = require('net');
var hosts = [['127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis', 9191]];

setInterval(function(){
    hosts.forEach(function(item) {
        var sock = new net.Socket();
        sock.setTimeout(2500);
        sock.on('connect', function() {
            console.log(item[0]+':'+item[1]+' is up.');
            sock.destroy();
        }).on('error', function(e) {
            console.log(item[0]+':'+item[1]+' is down: ' + e.message);
        }).on('timeout', function(e) {
            console.log(item[0]+':'+item[1]+' is down: timeout');
        }).connect(item[1], item[0]);
    });
}, 1000);
```

**Node JS Output**

> 127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis:9191 is down: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis:9191

Comment: A directory can't be pinged

Comment: What you can directory, can be a lot of things depending on the protocol. In HTTP protocol usually is a directory, but actually is called a path (as sometimes can be something else). If you want to check if that path exists, you have to connect to the HTTP server and make an HTTP request for that path, then check the returned status (200, 404).

Comment: This seems a bit crazy that a directory can not be pinged...

Comment: Could i do a HTTP Get and wait on response?

Comment: What is crazy is pinging something that can't receive connections, as a folder xD Joking apart. Yes, that's what you have to do. Open a connection to the HTTP server and make a request asking for the directory that you want to check. Then parse the response. As you see, you don't create a connection directly to the directory. You make a connection to the host and ASK for a directory. The host is the only one that can be pinged.

Comment: I'll try this Jorge, I just wanted to see if the libary could even do ti

Answer (score -1):

I'm not used to pinging through nodejs net package, but testing your code against a real website I found that

```
var hosts = [['as.com', 80]];
```

Do work, while

```
var hosts = [['as.com:80', 80]];
```

yields this error:

> as.com:80:80 is down: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

And in fact it seems the port is being set twice in your error reporting:

> 127.0.0.1:9191/api/WebApis:9191 is down: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Also, I made a test with a local PHP project served in 127.0.0.1:9191 and it worked too.

So maybe you just need to cut the port info in the string part of the hosts elements:

```
var hosts = [['127.0.0.1/api/WebApis', 9191]];
```

I just hope this helps, but as I said I'm not so used to this package.